# Delta sensitivity calculation according to SIMM

Tags: delta, sensitivities, initial-margin, isda-simm

According to [this article](https://ibkrcampus.com/ibkr-quant-news/delta-sensitivity-of-interest-rate-swap-part-i), in the ISDA SIMM methodology, the **delta** sensitivity for interest rate products is calculated using

$$ \text{delta} = \frac{V (x + 1 \text{bp}) - V (x - 1 \text{bp})}{2} $$

However, when I look into the [ISDA SIMM 2.5](https://www.isda.org/a/Pf2gE/ISDA-SIMM-v2.5.pdf) documentation, I fail to find any reference to the formula above. Could you please opine what is the basis of this delta calculation?

Comment: please keep in mind that if the interest rates are high enough, like Argentina's, then in practice you may need to use a bigger bump than 1bp.

Comment: ISDA is sadistic.  The 30-page document you linked to is just an appetizer.  If you want the main course (which is some 99% of the documentation), you need to get your employer's lawyers to talk to ISDA and then they may grant you access to a server from which you can download the proper documentation, which is some 40 MB heavy.

Comment: It is just the Central Difference or Symmetric difference formula for approximating a derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks for your comment. While your suggestion may be ideal, but I don't think that will be practical. As a general researcher I can only have access to public information (paid or free) not insider information

Comment: @Bogaso Are you affiliated with a university or research institute?  If so, use your academic email address and write to isdalegal@isda.org.  I am under the impression that ISDA only cares about waiving any legal liability for your potential misuses of SIMM